# JQuery - animate() color attribute only works for first tag?

Tags: jquery

Why is the following JQuery "color" effect only applied to the first p tag? The opacity effect works for all p tag. If I use `$("p#jp_test")`, it works for all `p` tag. I am confused.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jq_test").animate({
        left: '50px',
        opacity:'0.5',
        color: '#FF0000'}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the same `id` on more than one element, which is invalid. Use a class instead.

The reason `$("#jq_test")` only does the first and `$("p#jq_test")` does all of them is that when jQuery sees a selector that's purely an `id` selector, it uses `document.getElementById`, which is **very** fast, and returns a single element. But if it sees a selector that's more complex, it uses `querySelectorAll` (or its own handling in Sizzle on really old browsers), which finds all of them. But that's unspecified behavior; using the same `id` on more than one element is, again, invalid and a browser could choose not to find those elements via `querySelectorAll`, too, if it wanted.